# Configuring Annotations to be RUNTIME Retention By Default (without individual @Retention)

Tags: java, annotations

Is it possible to have a configuration where **all** Annotations of a given name or type are **automatically** `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`?

I came across a poblem where I need to use reflection at runtime to search for certain Annotations. But those are common Annotations scattered all over the app, such as `@Service` or `@Transactional`, and I can't go one by one and add `@RetentionPolicy` to each one, it would be too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java Language Specification, section [9.6.4.2. @Retention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.2) states:

> If T does not have a (meta-)annotation `m` that corresponds to `java.lang.annotation.Retention`, then a Java compiler **must** treat T as if it does have such a meta-annotation `m` with an element whose value is `java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.CLASS`.

As you can see, it is a strict requirement that missing annotation is same as `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)`.

If you need `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`, then you must explicitly specify that.